# Vaadin. Как запустить exe-файл на клиенте?

Tags: java, vaadin

Здравствуйте.

На есть серверное приложение с методом

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
...
}
```

который выводит в браузере табличные данные из БД.

Всё бы ничего, но возникла необходимость запустить **.exe файл** находящийся на клиентском компьютере с параметром взятым из той самой таблицы.

Если я пишу:

```
try
{
   String path = "C:\\Program Files\\file.exe";
   Runtime a = Runtime.getRuntime();
   Process proc = a.exec(path);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Notification.show(e.getMessage());
}
```

то при отладке, когда приложение ещё не опубликовано на сервере, всё работает хорошо.
**file.exe** запускается!
Но стоит мне опубликовать war-файл на удалённый TomCat-сервер, как сразу же срабатывает исключение **"Не удается найти указанный файл"**
Оно в общем то и понятно, на сервере нет **file.exe** и не должно быть.

Как бы заставить vaadin запускать экзешник на клиенте?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: если только через JS запускать на клиенте

Comment: То есть, в приложении на сервере я запускаю какой то-JS и он уже запускает .exe ?

Comment: нет. у тебя же web-приложение? крутится все в браузере. и когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку(пусть будет так для примера) в его браузере выполняется JS код, который запускает процесс

Comment: Да, у меня web-приложение. Всё в браузере. Но я даже примерно не представляю где это делать. Если Вас не затруднит, приведите пожалуйста примерчик, буду благодарен!